# Remove alpha ClutterActor

Tags: javascript, c, gnome, clutter

I have a clutter actor and I need it to be painted without transparency. I can get the background color and set alpha to 255, but that doesn't work with background images or border images. They are defined through CSS by the user, so I can't just edit them.

What I currently do to remove the background-color alpha:

```
let color = actor.get_background_color();
color.alpha = 255;
actor.set_background_color(color);
```

I am not who writes the actor. I'm a user of the actor so I can't rewrite its paint methods. Any way to flatten it?

Comment: Did you tag this question with "C" intentionally or should it be "CSS" instead? I can't see how C and JS go together here.

Comment: I intentionally tagged c and JavaScript. I'm using gjs so I could write it in JavaScript given a c function for the actor.

Comment: (My application is in JavaScript)